# basic multiplication is not working, the variable kg is multiplied by 2.205 to get the lbs conversion

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am getting weird outputs like 100kg =103 kg while the lbs to kg conversion is working perfectly fine,

```py
def calculate_1rm(weight_unit, squat, deadlift, bench_press, reps):
    try:
        squat, deadlift, bench_press, reps = float(squat), float(deadlift), float(bench_press), int(reps)
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input, please enter a number for all lifts"
    
    if weight_unit.lower() == "kg":
        squat = kg_to_lbs(squat)
        deadlift = kg_to_lbs(deadlift)
        bench_press = kg_to_lbs(bench_press)
        weight_unit = "lbs"
    if weight_unit.lower() == "lbs":
        squat = lbs_to_kg(squat)
        deadlift = lbs_to_kg(deadlift)
        bench_press = lbs_to_kg(bench_press)
        weight_unit = "kg"
```

I did not touch the values at all after these conversions

I have tried dividing by /.453592 (same result) and have tried just multiplying the variables (squat,deadlift,bench_press) by 2.205 but no luck

Comment: When doing kg⇒lbs, after line `weight_unit = "lbs"` executes, what do you think happens on the next line?

Comment: @spectras same spectras 

Comment: In other words, just change the second `if` to `elif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your second ‘if’ statement with ‘elif’. Modified code:

```
def calculate_1rm(weight_unit, squat, deadlift, bench_press, reps):
    try:
        squat, deadlift, bench_press, reps = float(squat), float(deadlift), float(bench_press), int(reps)
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input, please enter a number for all lifts"
    
    if weight_unit.lower() == "kg":
        squat = kg_to_lbs(squat)
        deadlift = kg_to_lbs(deadlift)
        bench_press = kg_to_lbs(bench_press)
        weight_unit = "lbs"
    elif weight_unit.lower() == "lbs":
        squat = lbs_to_kg(squat)
        deadlift = lbs_to_kg(deadlift)
        bench_press = lbs_to_kg(bench_press)
        weight_unit = "kg”
```